# How to force PhoneGap Android app to perform self-update?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I have this situation - PhoneGap app running in Android. It uses external API on my server. It might happen that I will change API structure so I will need to perform update of my mobile app to a newer version. Is there some automatic or half-automatic way how can I force update of the Phonegap app on the Android phone ?

I can display message to the user, that the app is outdated and he should go to Android Market and update the app from there, but I am looking for some more comfortable way how to force this update.

EDIT - Question specification:

I am not looking for a way how to load external script on application startup.
I am looking for PhoneGap-Android-specific solution how to invoke application update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've finally found a solution to my problem.

I use this [PhoneGap plugin](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins) to launch Android Intent, specifically its Intent.ACTION_VIEWS described [here in Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html).

This successfully fires Android Market App with the option to update my app.

Answer (score -1):

you can load your javascript-functions on initialization-time from your server.
If you have jQuery try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script>
function init() {
  $.getScript("http://yourserver.com/code.js", function(){} );
}

function doSomething() {
  alert('sorry! functions not loaded!');
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<input type=button value="doSomething();">

</body>
</html>
```

The file code.js look like

```
function doSomething() {
  alert('Doing something wonderful');
}
```

Comment: I am not looking for a way how to load external script on application startup.

I am looking for PhoneGap-Android-specific solution how to invoke application update.